# Delete everything except a word

Tags: regex, notepad++, google-sheets-api

I have hours searching for a way in regex to delete everything in a line except a certain text. It will be something like this:

**Before:**

```
Caracas
UNUSABLE TEXT Caracas UNUSABLE TEXT 
Caracas
```

**After:**

```
Caracas
Caracas
Caracas
Caracas
```

I have make so many tests with this:

**Find:** `.(text_you_need_to_keep).`

**Replace:** `$1`

But I can't get it to work.

Comment: Do you mean you want to replace a `UNUSABLE TEXT Caracas UNUSABLE TEXT` line with 3 `Caracas` lines?

Comment: Yeah, thats the objective.

Comment: Try `(Caracas)|\R*(?:(?!Caracas).)+\R*` and replace with `(?{1}$1:\nCaracas\n)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

*Find What*:      `(Caracas)|\R*(?:(?!Caracas).)+\R*`
*Replace With*: `(?{1}$1:\nCaracas\n)`

*Details*:

- `(Caracas)` - Group 1: `Caracas`
- `|` - or
- `\R*` - zero or more line breaks
- `(?:(?!Caracas).)+` - one or more chars other than line break chars (as many as possible) that does not start a `Caracas` char sequence
- `\R*` - zero or more line breaks

If the Group 1 matches, the replacement is just this Group 1 value, else, the replacement is a `Caracas` with newline chars on both ends.

See the regex demo:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It works really good. But i make a modification on the replace because it duplicates the lines for some reason. Now i use only $1 in the replace. Thanks again.